# How does mCPBA convert an amine to an N-oxide?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, redox

[image: mechanism]

Is this how the mechanism works? 
Since it is a very stereoselective reagent I thought maybe it proceed via one step only, but how would that then work?

Answer (score 5):

Firstly, any stereoselectivity in this reaction is not affected by the second step you drew (which is a simple proton transfer). This is because your second step neither creates nor destroys any stereochemistry present in the reactants.

However, mechanistically it is probably easier to deprotonate in the same step using the carbonyl oxygen of mCPBA.

[image: Mechanism for oxidation of amines to N-oxides]